# Explain the difference in code execution

Tags: java, try-catch

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Normal: " + testNormal());
        System.out.println("Exception: " + testException());
    }

    public static int testNormal() {
        try {
            // no exception
            return 0;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[normal] Exception caught");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("[normal] Finally");
        }
        System.out.println("[normal] Rest of code");
        return -1;
    }

    public static int testException() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[except] Exception caught");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("[except] Finally");
        }
        System.out.println("[except] Rest of code");
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Why are "[normal] Rest of Code" not executing and "[except]Rest of code" not executing? Please explain.

Comment: What part of the assignment do you not understand?

Comment: What do you think `return 0;` does?

Comment: `[except]Rest of code` is executing.

Answer (score 2):

1. `testNormal`. The `0` from `return 0` is stored somewhere, the code in the `finally` block ran, then that stored value is returned.
2. `testException`. The exception is thrown. The code in the `catch` is ran. Then the code in the `finally` block is ran. Program control then continues from the `System.out.println` and `-1` is returned.

A more interesting is the case where `finally` itself contains a `return`. In that case the return value in the `finally` block is returned and any stored value encountered from a previous `return` is discarded.